# Hide non VHD partitions

Tags: windows-7, images, partitioning, mount, vhd

I have two partition on my HDD: C and D. On D: I have a vhd image (with windows 7 ultimate) that I use to boot from.

When I'm running the OS from VHD I can still access my physical parititons. Is it possible to dismount them, in order to see just the virtual disks in the VHD OS? I tried with the physical C and it says that I cannot dismount a boot paritition and I think D cannot be dismounted because the VHD is on it.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you seeing the host system's drives C: and D: from within the VM? If so, what drive letters are they assigned? It might also help to know what virtualisation platform you are using. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using the feature offered by Windows 7 Ultimate that allows me to boot directly from a VHD file. Like presented here: http://blogs.msdn.com/knom/archive/2009/04/07/windows-7-vhd-boot-setup-guideline.aspx